# how to format larger dataframe better using pdfwriter using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When a large dataframe is been transformed to a pdf it tries fit too much on to one page so information looks small on pdf. How can I fix this so it formats correctly for small and larger dataframes?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))

ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title(title)
ax.table(cellText=panda_df.values, colLabels=panda_df.columns, loc='center')
pdf.savefig(fig,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Comment: so should I add a font size?